# How to use a Python REPL in a script

Tags: python, scripting

I am learning Python to use QT with Python, not only C++, and am curious if I can embed a Python interpreter in my application as a REPL?

I want to allow users to script either loading a file and that file act as a plugin, or by evaluating code entered in a text box or something similar to embedding the interpreter in C or C++ and script the application using Python.

Can this be done if the application is itself written in Python and made into a standalone binary using py2exe or something similar, something like Anders did with the C# REPL or Miguel with Mono.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is all certainly possible, but it is not beginner stuff.

Python offers a [read-eval loop](http://docs.python.org/library/code.html#) as a module, but you'd still have so create a console in QT where you can type in input and display results.

The same goes for a plugin system. It's very easy to import a script as a plugin and the plugin just has to import your application to access its state. But that's hardly a real plugin system, you'd want to create a proper API so the plugins don't break whenever something in the app changes.

Comment: Would you say it is easier to build the application in c++/qt and allow scripting in python using boost.python or something similar than to build the app in python/qt and allow scripting in python?

Comment: No, using Python is much easier. If you wrote your application in C++, you'd have to write an extra Python wrapper for it's C++ API. If you write it in Python plugins can call the API directly.